# AppSettings in markup issue

Tags: asp.net, appsettings

I am trying to put this in my markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%$ AppSettings:proxyScriptUrl %>"></script>
```

But for some reason this is not accepted. What am I doing wrong here?

The requirement is that I do not use a helper method but that the expressionbuilder is used in the markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx), that's not allowed:

> If you want to use an expression as a static value on your page or control, you use an expression as part of an ASP.NET server control. A typical strategy is to add a Literal control and set its Text property to an expression. For example, to place a copyright notice at the bottom of every page you could use the following:

```
<p align="center">
  <asp:Literal runat="server" text="<%$ AppSettings: copyright %>"/>
</p>
```

This might help you if want to do it all in the aspx file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<asp:Literal id="literal1" runat="server" text="<%$ AppSettings: jsSource %>" />'></script>
```

Note the unpleasant single quotes in the text variable - trying to us escaped double quotes results in "Badly formed script tag" errors.

---

**Edit:** apologies - I've swapped the order around this does work.

Comment: For that renders this in html:

    <script type='text/javascript' src='<%$ AppSettings: proxyScriptUrl %>'></script>

I was expecting that it would render the value of the appsetting itself instead.

Answer (score 5):

When I do this I usually create a helper class I like to call Config and put a static property on there for the App Settings in question.

Then your code would become:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Config.ProxyScriptUrl%>"/>
```

Some of the other benefits of this is that if I decide to move the ProxyScriptUrl to a different configuration mechanism I only have to modify the one class. Your config class might look like:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static string ProxyScriptUrl 
    {
        get
        {
            return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxyScriptUrl "];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know but I need to do this one with the expressionbuilder inside the markup.